# Androidmarker not found

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm following this tutorial to add an overlay to a google map (http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).

```
mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker); //there is no androidmarker.png in res folder
itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
```

Where can I find this icon (hdpi/ldpi and mdpi version)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial cleary states:

> First, we need the image that we'll
>   use for our map overlay. Here, we'll
>   use the Android on the right as our
>   marker. Drag this image (or your own)
>   to the res/drawable/ directory of your
>   project workspace.

[image: androidmarker]

So if you are really searching for this specific androidmarker, use the one from the tutorial. You can use any other marker if you like.